# TSQL working out total worked days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to work out the total number of days worked from various different tables. I have a timesheet table and timesheet line table. The timesheetline table has the following fields:

```
Id; TimesheetId;    TimesheetLineCode;  WorkUnitId; EntryGroupId;   WorkerId;   
Day1_Standard_RateId;   Day1_Standard_Hours;    
Day2_Standard_RateId;   Day2_Standard_Hours ;
Day3_Standard_RateId;   Day3_Standard_Hours ;
Day4_Standard_RateId;   Day4_Standard_Hours ;
Day5_Standard_RateId;   Day5_Standard_Hours ;
Day6_Standard_RateId;   Day6_Standard_Hours ;
Day7_Standard_RateId;   Day7_Standard_Hours ;
ConcurrencyToken    ;
```

Now if a person has worked 3 hours in day 1 and worked 5 hours in day 5 then total worked days are 2 for that week. How do i work out total work days between two dates using these fields

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
  WorkerId,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Day1_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN Day2_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN Day3_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN Day4_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN Day5_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN Day6_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN Day7_Standard_Hours > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalDays
FROM timesheetline
GROUP BY WorkerId
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, I want to display name and last name so does that mean i have to group by a;; the columns i display

Comment: @ShahbazHussain - Yes, add them in the select `SELECT 
  WorkerId, name, lastname ...` and in the `group by workerId, name, lastname`.

Comment: Whta if i now what to work out the toal number of hours each worker has worked between these two dates

Comment: Just add SUM(Day1_Standard_Hours + Day2_Standard_Hours +Day3_Standard_Hours + Day4_Standard_Hours+ Day5_Standard_Hours+ Day6_Standard_Hours + Day7_Standard_Hours) AS TotalHours to the query above.

Comment: When im trying to work the toal days worked between 2 dates, it doesnt give me the right figures

Comment: The answer was slightly wrong as it was taking into account the worker 0 hours as a worked day. so i had to change it from >= 0 to >0.